# Can't add user on system

Tags: user

I tried to add user on GUI but nothing happens.

I have already tried by command line but I recived the message below:

useradd: existing lock file /etc/subuid.lock without a PID
useradd: não foi possível travar /etc/subuid; tente novamente mais tarde.
adduser: '/usr/sbin/useradd -d /home/cfs -g cfs -s /bin/bash -u 1004 cfs' retornou código de erro 16. Saindo.

Comment: i can add user from gui, is locked.
I need also login from active directory user, i have joined domain but
i can't change user in login interface
thank you
Alberto

Answer (score 1):

The error message means no process is actually using the existing lock file, though its existence prevents your current action from completing.

Delete it and try again.

`sudo rm /etc/subuid.lock`

Comment: We typically prefer GUI methods over straight Terminal commands. Perhaps guide the user through opening a Files window as an administrator, locating and deleting the file?